# UTF-8 encoding issues on my website

Tags: utf8-decode

I'm stuck with the encoding of my site it didn't encode correctly the site to utf-8 but cannot figure it out where i've done wrong here is the example to check it out if someone is interested to help me.
For ex this link:
www.mkmeme.com/meme/eoj37h

when you view the source the  tag code is:

```
<title>&#1046;&#1077;&#1085;&#1072;&#1090;&#1072; &#1090;&#1088;&#1077;&#1073;&#1072; &#1076;&#1072; &#1079;&#1085;&#1072;&#1077; 70 &#1088;&#1072;&#1073;&#1086;&#1090;&#1080;!..... </title>
```

and the correct code need to be

```
<title>Жената треба да знае 70 работи!.....</title>
```

Hope someone will help me out with this

Comment: For me is working correctly. Maybe you changed some configuration in your browser. I used Firebug to change the HTML content of your title tag, with russian chars and worked.

Comment: Marcelo i've tried on other computers and it is showing the same unencoded tags inside the <title> tag in the source

Answer (score 0):

It appears in the browser correctly for me ...

[image: Tab Title Screenshot]

I would recommend leaving as is. Plus the items are html entities so you need to decode them as html entities.

Comment: Yes but why does the source code matter if it's generating what it should be. ie the name on the tab.

Comment: It is the problem in the source code as it sayd Marcelo Assis, and the source code matters Ben because when the for example google spiders crawl the content they will show the text that it is inside the <title> tag in the source and that is not good